# How can I get rid of the duplicates in my database and still be able to link the index?

Tags: csv, neo4j

I have a csv called Rooms that has 2 columns, the name off rooms and a classid

When I feed them in to Neo4j and set up the relationship by joining all the other csvs on the classid I can match them fine. The problem is though when I match them it returns 3 seperate nodes like this.

Room2---otherNodes Room2---otherNodes Room2---otherNodes

How can I have it that when I display the relationship it just shows Room2 Once and then all the related nodes connecting to it?

I tried using merge but it doesnt keep all my classids, it only keeps one. So when I try join up the relationships on classid its doesnt work right.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Module.csv" AS row1
Merge (p:Module{ModuleName: row1.Module_Name})
ON CREATE set p.ClassId = row1.ClassId


LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Lecturers.csv" AS row2
Merge (m:Lecturer{Lecturer:row2.Lecturer})
ON CREATE set m.ClassId = row2.ClassId

MATCH (c:Module),(o:Lecturer)
WHERE c.ClassId = o.ClassId
CREATE (c)-[:TAUGHT_BY]->(o)
```

CSV:

```
Modules:
Module_Name ClassId
math        1
english     2
geography   3
math        4
Computers   5


Lecturers:
teacher1   1
teacher2   2
teacher3   3
teacher1   4
teacher3   5
```

Comment: Can you add the query which loads the CSV and creates the nodes and relationships?

Comment: I added a query that I thought would do the job but now im getting a new error which ive posted as well

Comment: Not a good idea to do two LOAD CSVs back to back like this. Since it doesn't know how they relate to each other, you're going to get a cartesian product of all the rows of Module.csv against all the rows of Lecturers.csv. That can easily blow up your memory.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the CSVs? Is a single Lecturer only supposed to have one Module and one ClassId? Is a single Module only supposed to have one ClassId?

Comment: I changed the queries back to the first way but I still have the original problem

Comment: It sounds like Lecturers (and maybe Modules too?) have multiple ClassIds in the CSV files. Is that so?

Comment: I've added a edit explaining, teacher 3 should be a node with the relationship TAUGHT BY connecting computers and geo but right now it just connects to one so it would only show it node connecting to computers when I click TAUGHT_BY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your Lecturers.csv. You have the same lecturers on multiple lines with different ClassIds. That means we can't do a simple MERGE with ON CREATE, since the last row processed for that lecturer will be the last one to set your ClassId property.

Instead, you might want to create the relationships as you process your Lecturers.csv:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Lecturers.csv" AS row2
MERGE (m:Lecturer{Lecturer:row2.Lecturer})
WITH m, row2
MATCH (c:Module{ClassId:row2.ClassId})
MERGE (c)-[:TAUGHT_BY]->(m)
```

Comment: It says WITH is required? I tried adding it before and after match but it doesnt work, im gunna look into the WITH keyoword

Comment: Forgot about that, query should be fixed